# Difference between iptables rules and firewall rules?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am renting a vps and the company I rent from has firewall settings where I am allowed 20 rules. Then I have the iptables on my server. I have just setup some rules on the iptables that I found from a blog regarding FTP,SSH,Web,etc...

I'm not sure how the firewall with the 20 rules differs from iptables, I don't know what rules to implement.

My purpose at the moment is a basic LAMP webserver.

Comment: How does your provider present these "20 rules" to you?  Through some kind of web-configuration interface?

Comment: Well I called their tech support and they told me that I get up to 20 rules. Yeah there is a web interface. I create firewall, then enable firewall, check out rules, configure firewall, add rule, presented with priority, action(refuse/authorize),protocol,ip source. Again these seem redundant as I worked with TCP/UDP on the iptables. I have a dynamic ip address so I figured setting a connection ip-address didn't seem to make sense. Although maybe the 192 type ip-address doesn't change?

Comment: You need to ask them whether that 'firewall' is a hardware firewall or a software firewall. Having two layers can be good, but 20 rules seems artificially restricted.

Answer (score 1):

iptables is an app that allows to configure the tables provided by the Linux kernel firewall 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables

So iptables - the architecture, the rules format/syntax is specific to Linux firewall, though conceptually it is rather common/generic.

More generally a firewall can be based on a variety of other platforms.

If you have root access your linux vps you could set up your own rules,
but you may have limited access 
and your provider probably allows you to add a few custom configurations limited to 20 via some web front end.